# Content description for the individual items of a resource string array

Tags: android, android-resources, android-a11y, accessibility

I have a spinner which is filled with the following string array from resources.

```
<string-array name="units_array_area">
    <item>kg/hectare</item>
    <item>kg/acre</item>
    <item>lb/hectare</item>
    <item>lb/acre</item>
</string-array>
```

Now if the selected item is `kg/hectare`, TalkBack pronounces it as "kug slash hectare", which doesn't make any sense. How can I make it pronounce "*kilograms per hectare*" while still displaying `kg/hectare`?